# MySQL Theory: Single DB for multiple companies

Tags: mysql

I have design question for MySQL. As a side project, I am attempting to create a cloud based safety management system. In the most basic terms, a company will subscribe to the service, which will manage company document record as blobs, corrective, employee information, audit results.

My initial design concept was to have a seperate DB for each company.

However, the question I have is if user access control is secure, would it be ok to have all the companies under one DB? What are the pitfalls of this? Are there any performance issues to consider? For identifying records, would it be a compound key of the company and referenceID number unique for each company? If so when generating a reference number for a record of a company, would it slow down as the record set increases?

In terms of constraints, I would expect up to 2000 companies and initially a maximum of 1000 records per company growing at 5% per year. I expect a maximum of 2 gig of blob storage per company growing at 10% per year. The system is to run one cloud server whether multiple db or one big one.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two question : performance and security.

If you use the same mysql user, security will not be different from one option to the other.

If you need performance, you can have the same results, running one or multiple databases (see for instance mysql partioning).

But there are others things that you should consider: like how it will be easy to have one database for your website... or like how it would be easy to have one database per user.

In fact, I give you an answer : considering the size of your data, don't make a choice on performance matters that are quite significantly equals for your needs, but on the choice that will make your life easy.

Comment: Thanks to both. The intention is that each company would have multiple users logging into the DB. I'll need to look further into what is the best solution for me then in terms of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

If there is not much inter-company interaction and overall frequent statistics and you don't plan to make application updates every week or so which would impact the DB structure, I'd go with separate DB (and DB user) for each company. It's more scalable, less prone to user access bugs and easier to make some operations such as remove a company.

On the other hand, 2 mil entries is not such a big deal and if you plan to develop the application further, keeping it in one DB could be better approach.